# Import Class Path Location in dwl Mule

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

In Munit , i'm using the  Response asset to do Validation, not sure how to import the multi level folder path in dwl
, if i have multiple folder path like `sample_data/response/address.dwl`  it is not working(`import sample_data/response::address` not liking the `/` also `.`), On keeping single folder followed by filename working `import sample_data::address`.

Not sure, syntax for multilevel folder on dwl import?

Tried in both RunTime 4.3 and 4.2.2? Any Thought please. Thanks.

```
        <munit:validation >
          <munit-tools:assert doc:name="Assert payload" doc:id="9df23ba1-befd-4da9-b8aa-a95b5b59efff" message="The payload does not match">
            <munit-tools:that ><![CDATA[#[%dw 2.0
           import sample_data::address
          // how to import  multiple folder path sample_data/response::address???

            ---
            address::main({payload: payload})]]]></munit-tools:that>
         </munit-tools:assert>
       </munit:validation>
```

Thanks in advance.
Let me know if question requires details. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with below code.

```
<munit:validation >
      <munit-tools:assert doc:name="Assert payload" doc:id="9df23ba1-befd-4da9-b8aa-a95b5b59efff" message="The payload does not match">
        <munit-tools:that ><![CDATA[#[%dw 2.0
       import sample_data::response::address
      // how to import  multiple folder path sample_data/response::address???

        ---
        address::main({payload: payload})]]]></munit-tools:that>
     </munit-tools:assert>
   </munit:validation>
```

Comment: Perfect.Having thought about it. Thank you for the fast reply.